# What data can i collect from firebase with the different auth providers?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to use the firebase Auth Providers to sign in users, my problem is I don't know the data sent back about the user from the auth providers.

I wish to collect data like Name, Email address, Gender, Country... But I am not sure what is sent back about the user.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth will return additional IdP user information after sign-in. Here is an example with web (this is also available for Android and iOS):

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider())
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Additional user info from IdP.
    // This object includes email, first_name, granted_scopes, id, last_name, picture, etc.
    console.log(userCredential.additionalUserInfo.profile);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```